# How to write the response to a file in HTTP Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have HTTP Handler where I want to log the response. I know there is option `context.Request.SaveAs(filename..`. But I never tried this before. How can I use this, I mean someone can be more specific about file name?

Comment: Decide if you want to save the `Request` or `Response`.

Comment: @nunespascal- I want to save Request

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.saveas.aspx) is pretty straight forward about this:

> The [SaveAs] call specifies that the request be saved as a text file
>   in a directory where the ASP.NET process identity has been granted
>   write permissions, and that any header information included in the
>   request is included in the file.

You can thus simply save the entire HttpRequest (including the headers in a file). You can simply determine the path and a boolean indicating whether you want to incude the headers as well:

```
context.Request.SaveAs(@"c://myLogFile.log",true)
```